# How to pass argument in firefoxprofile?

Tags: java, selenium

To avoid hardcoding of the pathname to my download folder, I am using XML file to store my pathname.

Here is the code:

```
public class Driver 
{

    //public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(FFprofile());


    public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(FFprofile(downloadPath));


    // Method to handle firefox browser profile
    //public static FirefoxProfile FFprofile()
    public static FirefoxProfile FFprofile(String downloadPath)
    {

        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

        //String downloadPath="C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Downloads";

        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", downloadPath);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/vnd.ms-excel,application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);  
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
        profile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

        return profile;
    }

}
```

Now issue is that there is error in line:

```
public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(FFprofile(downloadPath));
```

Error is:

```
downloadPath cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

The snap of my XML file:

```
<parameter name="downloadPath" value="C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads"/>
```

Please guide me how to handle the error?

Comment: Seems you are not reading from the file properly. Refer this example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/